# Python Telegram Bot + 3rd Party Listener

Tags: python, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm working with Python Telegram Bot https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/

I'm trying to implement a bot function into a 3rd party listener, so when the handle_event() is fired, with a telegram username as parameter, the bot bans that member from the group. here we go with an example:

```
def handle_event(event):

        result = offerCancelled_event.processReceipt(receipt) 

        #Double check if we got a result
        if(result):

            #Set telegram user
            telegram_user = "Ulvur"

            users.remove(telegram_user)
            file = open('users.txt', 'w+')
            for user in users:
                file.write('%s\n' % user)
                file.close()

            if(telegram_user not in users):
                Update.effective_chat.ban_member(telegram_user)
```

Following code is returning `AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'ban_member'` when function is fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Update` is a class and the property `Update.effective_chat` can only be properly evaluated for instances of that class. If you want to make simple calls to the Bot API, you should instantiate an instance of the `telegram.Bot` class and call its methods - in your case [`Bot.ban_chat_member`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.ban_chat_member). Please see the [Introduction to the API](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Introduction-to-the-API) for a more detailed explanation of how to use the API methods.

Comment: As helpful as always!
So, i added the following lines on the function:

bot = telegram.Bot(token='TOKEN')
bot.ban_chat_member(chat, telegram_user)

To make a point here for further views... I cannot pass to the ban_chat_member() function the telegram username but the userId. So I had to change a bit my project workflow.